# Adding UITableView as subview to UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a situation where I have a `UICollectionViewController` whose cells are all full screen. There is a button on each cell which should popup a menu. I've implemented this as a `UIView` with a `UITableView` on it using the `UICollectionViewController` as the delegate and datasource for the `UITableView`, but after adding the `UITableView`, the app crashes with an exception, [NSIndexPath _needsSetup] : unrecognized selector.

Is it possible to have a `UICollectionViewController` be a UITableViewDataSource and `UITableViewDelegate`? I'm wondering if it's getting screwed up on being the datasource for both the `UITableView` and its `UICollectionView`.

Any thoughts?...

Thanks!

Comment: pls show the code related to  _needsSetup.

Comment: It should be possible - post your code - but presenting a UITableViewController in a popover might be simpler.